# Variables are not getting replaced in powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was using start-process cmdlet in powershell as

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$Installer_Path" -Args '/s /v"/qb SETUPTYPE=\"$Setup_type\" USERNAME=$user_name PASSWORD=$password SERVER=$sql_server INSTALLDIR=\"$Transfer_Path\\\" SHAREPATH=\"$Transfer_Path\\\""' –Wait
```

In the above command the variable are not getting replaced except $Installer_Path. I believe issue is because of variables located inside ' " " '. Could any one help me with the variable substitution?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it returning as?

Comment: It was triggering the installer with out replacing the variables with actual values.

Comment: Does your installer take those specific variables? Try googling "powershell escape characters", if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using single quotes and not double quotes. In order for your variables to expand you need to use double quotes. If you have to use double quotes inside of those you can escape them by preceding them with a backtick ` or by doubling them up "".

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$Installer_Path" -Args "/s /v`"/qb SETUPTYPE=\`"$Setup_type\`" USERNAME=$user_name PASSWORD=$password SERVER=$sql_server INSTALLDIR=\`"$Transfer_Path\\\`" SHAREPATH=\`"$Transfer_Path\\\`"`"" –Wait
```

Comment: Thank you...resolved my issue